# Get the total of a column using sap gui

Tags: vba, sap-gui

Have a question that I just cant find an answer for. I have this value displayed (in yellow):

[image]

It's the total of the values in the column. Do you know how I can just get this value ? Usually in my macro I export the entire table in a excel workbook, open it and find the value of the last cell.
I there an easier and faster way of getting it ?

Thanks

Comment: By the screenshot I guess it is a [grid view](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/760.01/en-US/4af24c3281fb4d6a809e53238562d3b2.html). You can use SAPGUI scripting to connect to SAPGUI, connect to the object, get the number of rows and retriev the value in the last row with `objectname.GetCellValue(rowNr,colName)`

Comment: How can I get the number of rows ?

Comment: WIth `objectname.rowcount` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP did not post any code I can only guess by the screen shot that the last row of a [grid view](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/760.01/en-US/4af24c3281fb4d6a809e53238562d3b2.html) should be retrieved.

The following code snippet should do this. Assumption is that the variable `ses` is connected to the right session depicted in the OP's screenshot

```
dim ses as object
' here code to connect to the sap session

dim tbl as object
set tbl = ses.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
With tbl
   .firstVisibleRow = .rowCount -1
   Debug.Print  .getcellValue (.rowCount -1, "COLNAME")
End With
```

Comment: I might have a problem with the "COLNAME" value, as you typed it I assume it's a string value but I tried every "names" of the column and I can't get a value. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Yes, it has to be the column name from your grid view. Looking at your picture  it could be "Quantite de odre" or something like that. You can also try to find out the column name as described [here](https://www.synactive.com/tips/tip_sapgrid_2.html). Or you retrieve it via `table.GetColumnTitles("0")(0)`

Comment: Aaaaaaand it worked !
Problem was .rowcount, I needed .rowcount-1
Anyway, thanks a lot!